# Display [key, value] from `Map` onto html table

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, ejs

I have an empty JS `Map` object (called dct) that I'd like to iterate through and display key, value into a html `table`. The `Map` will be populate from another page, at the moment the items are added manually to check if the display works

I've tried `dct.forEach(...)` or `for (var [key, value] of dct.entries())` but the error being `dct.forEach is not a function` I don't think the problem is with the way I iterate the `Map`, but maybe with the way I create it or use it.

**routes.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require("cookie-session");
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var urlEncoderParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false});

var app = express();

app.use(session({secret: "secret"}))

.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof(req.session.dct) == "undefined") {
        req.session.dct = new Map();
        req.session.dct.set(0, "z");
        req.session.dct.set(1, "o");
    }
    next();
})

.get("/home/", function(req, res)  {
    res.render("home.ejs", {dct: req.session.dct});
})

.listen(8080);
```

**home.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My items</h1>

        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Item number</th>
                <th>Item value</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <% dct.forEach(function(value, key) { %>
                    <td> <%= value %> </td>
                    <td> <%= key %> </td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                <% }); %>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The html table should be filled with two rows, the columns as below:

```
|  z  |  0  |  Delete  |
|  o  |  1  |  Delete  |
```

Thank you

Comment: method is `forEach()` not `foreach()` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed, but that didn't solve my problem, now I get `dct.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I think the problem is, you are using `cookie-session` which serializes the session data to a cookie with JSON. The `Map` is not being serialized in a way that allows it to be recovered on next request. Only add basic JSON data to session, like strings, arrays, numbers, etc.

Comment: I changed the Map to an Array but the error is the same, it is as the line `req.session.dct = [];` does not work. 


I put the same line into `.get("/home/", function(req, res)  {`, it does work but I can't add items since the dct is erased every time I land on home.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map1 = new Map();

map1.set('0', 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'bar');

var iterator1 = map1.entries();

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: ["0", "foo"]

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: [1, "bar"]
```

Comment: Thank you, though could you be more specific please? As is it, I fail to see how that answers my question (Create and populate Map (or Array) in routes.js, and display it via home.ejs)

Comment: I actually dont see where is the problem in your code. Maybe I would try to remove the if statement in your middleware to make sur the map is created. And I  would write app.use() app.get() add app.listen() just to be sure.